# Figuring out bi-grams in a section of cipher text

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, frequency

Trying to figure out why my bi-gram counter is not properly sequencing through my array and keeping the correct count for matches. Help would be much appreciated.

EXAMPLE --> "**DL**KJGJFF**DL**JD**DL**JL**DL**FK" 
ANSWER  -->DL = 4

```html
        int cipherTxt_length = cipherTxt.length();
        String ch;
        int count=0;
        for(char i='a'; i<='z'; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("inside first for loop -- count -- "+count);
                for(char k='a'; k<='z'; k++)
                {
                    System.out.println("inside first for loop -- count -- "+count);
                    count = 0;
                    for(int j=0; j<cipherTxt_length; j++)
                    {
                        System.out.println("inside first for loop -- count -- "+count);
                        ch=cipherTxt.substring(j,j+2); //extracting characters of the string one by one
                        if(ch.charAt(j)==k && ch.charAt(j+2)==i) //first checking the whole string for 'a', then 'b' and so on
                        count++; //increasing count of those aplhabets which are present in the string   
                    }
                    if(count!=0)//printing only those aphabets whose count is not '0'
                    {
                        System.out.println(i+"\t\t"+count);//\t is tabbing method
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String s =  "DLKJGJFFDLJDDLJLDLFK";
Map<String, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, s.length() - 1)
    .mapToObj(i -> s.substring(i, i + 2))
    .collect(HashMap::new, (m, e) -> m.compute(e, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1), (m, n) -> m.putAll(n));
Entry<String, Integer> max = map.entrySet().stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue)).get();
System.out.println(max);    // -> DL=4
```